# the .getText function of my textfield isn't in sync

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, fxml

I'm writing a fxml project and there is a textfield with this handler:

```
@FXML
    private void action (KeyEvent event) throws ParseException, IOException {
        System.out.println(textField.getText());
    }
```

but the problem is for example if i write "problem" in the textfield, the output i get is "proble" , it's like the actionhandler is always one step behind! how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Why not listen to the `text` property of the `TextField`? Or, if you only want to do something when the user presses "Enter", use an `onAction` handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that your `textField` is being updated after the key has been released but this event is occuring when the key is being pressed. If I were you I would try either:

- testing for the `EventType` and printing only after release, so something like:
  `if (event.getEventType() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) ...` (see [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html))
  ,  or
- just taking the key that was pressed at the end from `event.getText()` and appending to the string from `textField.getText()` (kind of hacky though)

Neither are ideal imo but it's where I would start. Good luck!